# Meteor fullcalendar external dragging style crash

Tags: fullcalendar, meteor

I am trying to copy example of external-dragging at meteor application:
http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/external-dragging.html

If you drag event from the left to the calendar, event will have blue background.
[image: fullcalendar-ok]

It's ok.

I am creating new application

```
mrt create test
cd test
mrt add jquery
mrt add fullcalendar
```

then I am downloading jquery-ui to /client/external

and starting meteor

```
mrt
```

When I am dragging events from the left to the calendar, calendar event background lost:
[image: fullcalendar-problem]

Help me please solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact problem a few days ago. It is because the fullcalendar-print.css is also being loaded. I ended up removing the fullcalendar mrt package and just including the js and css files (except for the print one) into my meteor project.

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent one day trying to fix it. I will contact author of package.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't feel bad I did too. When I realized what it was...facepalm